# Start SMBD (Samba) with profiling parameter (For NetData)

Tags: debian, samba, monitoring, smb, settings

I am trying to set up Netdata monitoring on my debian server. Netdata works with everything but Samba. To get it to recognize samba I have to do the following: 
`smbd` must be started either with the `-P 1` option or inside `smbd.conf` using `smbd profiling level`

I have no idea on how I am supposed to do this. I have done everything else the document told me todo. 
(Here is the link to the webpage: https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/agent/collectors/python.d.plugin/samba/)

I have made it so the `netdata` user has sudo permissions. I just can't figure out how to enable the profiling. I have looked over all of the internet (meaning I spent a long time stuck on this) and found nothing but the link that I provided you and tutorials on how to setup samba. None of those even mention being able to setup the profiling. The only thing that did was the man page but it just said:

```
smbd profiling level (G)

    This parameter allows the administrator to enable profiling support.

    Possible values are off, count and on.

    Default: smbd profiling level = off

    Example: smbd profiling level = on
```

I tried sticking that into the smb.conf but no luck. When I did `sudo smbstatus -P 1` I got no profile found.

Can someone please explain to me how to set this up? Is it a setting in the smb.conf? If so where does it go and what does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `profiling level = on` inside the smb.conf (probably /etc/samba/smb.conf) should work. Then restart both services, i.e. `systemctl restart smb`
Here is what the smb.conf looks like:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   # Enable profiling for netdata
   smbd profiling support = on
...

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
...
```

Comment: I changed the profiling support to `smbd profiling level = on` in the smb.conf but now all I get is `Profile data unavailable`. I am back to where I started. What am I doing wrong? XS

Comment: You might not be doing anything wrong, was your version of Samba built with profiling support, it normally isn't by default.

Comment: How would I find that out? When I had installed it all I did was `sudo apt install samba` and then configured it. Will I have to reinstall it?

Comment: Just checked, Debian doesn't build with profiling support, so if you want profiling, you will have to build Samba yourself.